# Using Geospatial Features Implemented in SXA with a Custom Search Index - Run-time Error

Tags: sxa, azure-search

After manually implementing support for the `Edm.GeographyPoint` field type (per [Is it possible to get Azure Search to support EDM.GeographyPoint?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/is-it-possible-to-get-azure-search-to-support-edm-geographypoint)), I was happy to notice an answer on a related question from [Dawid Rutkowski](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/851/dawid-rutkowski) ([Using Sitecore SXA Location Search with Azure Search](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/using-sitecore-sxa-location-search-with-azure-search/18015#18015)) indicating that the SXA team has implemented this same functionality.

I've converted my custom index configurations over to use the relevant SXA types (e.g. `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex`). **I'm able to rebuild my index in Sitecore and see good values in the Azure index**, for example:

```
...
"geo_coordinate": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    -90.169,
    33.4945
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties":
    {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  }
}
...
```

Now, I'm trying to *query* the index using the Sitecore search API and am getting the following run-time error:

```
Constructor on type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.LinqToCloudIndex`1[[Acme.Foundation.Search.Models.FooResult, Acme.Foundation.Search, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.

at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex.<>c.<InitializeServiceCollectionClient>b__2_0(ServiceBuilder builder)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.ServiceCollection.GetInstance(Type concreteType, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.ServiceCollection.GetInstance[T](Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchSearchContext.GetQueryable[TItem](IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
   at Acme.Foundation.Search.Repositories.FooRepository.GetFoos(...)
...
```

Here are my index configurations:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore search:require="azure">
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultAzureFoosIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration">
          <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="geo_coordinate" boost="1f" facetable="NO" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.Geospatial.GeoPoint" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure" />
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
          <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration/documentOptions">
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="geo_coordinate">Acme.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.CoordinateComputedIndexField, Acme.Foundation.Search</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultAzureFoosIndexConfiguration>
    </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/" xmlns:tenant="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/tenant/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" search:require="azure">
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="foo_web_index" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="connectionStringName">cloud.search</param>
            <param desc="totalParallelServices">5</param>
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultAzureFoosIndexConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                  <Limit>1000</Limit>
                </policy>
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Tenant/Global/Foos/</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
            <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
            <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I'm creating the search context as per usual:

```
var ctx = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("foo_web_index").CreateSearchContext();
```

...and am querying the index like so:

```
var results = ctx.GetQueryable<FooResult>().Where(...)...;
```

The run-time error is thrown on this line (on `GetQueryable<T>()`).

**What I have verified/tried thus far:**

- My custom index configs are patched *after* `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Azure.config` (`...\App_Config\Modules\SXA\Z.Foundation.Overrides\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Azure.config`) and should therefore pick up all the SXA goodness.
- There aren't ostensibly any `<param />` elements I'm missing.
- The run-time type of the search context is `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.CloudSearchSearchContext`, as expected.
- Inheriting from `SearchResultItem` on `FooResult` doesn't change the error.
- Adding a parameterless constructor on `FooResult` doesn't change the error.
- Referencing an OOTB SXA index rather than the custom index (e.g. `sitecore_sxa_web_index`) yields the same error; it doesn't seem to be unique to the index.

Reflecting `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.dll`, I think this is the method interest:

```
protected virtual ServiceCollectionClient InitializeServiceCollectionClient()
{
  ServiceCollectionClient collectionClient = new ServiceCollectionClient();
  collectionClient.Register(typeof (LinqToCloudIndex<>), (Func<ServiceBuilder, object>) (builder => ServiceBuilder.CreateInstanceOfType(typeof (LinqToCloudIndex<>), builder.Types.ToArray<Type>(), (object) builder.Arguments)));
  collectionClient.Register(typeof (AbstractSearchIndex), (Func<ServiceBuilder, object>) (builder => (object) this));
  collectionClient.Register(typeof (QueryStringBuilder), (Func<ServiceBuilder, object>) (builder => (object) new QueryStringBuilder(new FilterQueryBuilder(), new SearchQueryBuilder(), true)));
  return collectionClient;
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
collectionClient.Register(typeof (LinqToCloudIndex<>), (Func<ServiceBuilder, object>) (builder => ServiceBuilder.CreateInstanceOfType(typeof (LinqToCloudIndex<>), builder.Types.ToArray<Type>(), (object) builder.Arguments)));
```

As this is reflected code, the empty `<>` probably indicates a cast but, I got nothing .

**What am I missing?**

- Something in the configs?
- Some fancy thing with DI?
- A specific way to instantiate the search context?

**Version notes:**

- `Sitecore XP 9.1.1 rev. 002459`
- `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.8.1 rev. 190319`

Comment: have you tried using `FooResult` using the `sitecore_web_index` to rule out the index itself being the issue?

Comment: Yes, we have implemented geospatial features in SXA. They are not available out of the box in Sitecore. That is the reason why we have our own overrides for `LinqToCloudIndex` or `CloudSearchProviderIndex`. Those need to be used in order to have properly working features like ordering by distance or searching within a radius. Few questions... What version of SXA do you have? Why you have custom `geo_coordinate` fields instead of SXA ones? Why are you using custom computed field type `Acme.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.CoordinateComputedIndexField` instead of SXA one?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski Thanks for the comment! We're using `Sitecore XP 9.1.1 rev. 002459` with `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.8.1 rev. 190319`. I have a custom template that also has a `coordinate` field; I wanted to use a custom `geo_coordinate` field just to keep things separate and avoid collision/confusion. The custom computed field exists for the same reason and is keyed to my own `coordinate` field.

Comment: @BenLipson That's a good idea. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @BenLipson Temporarily hard coding the index name as `"sitecore_sxa_web_index"` (meaning `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_sxa_web_index").CreateSearchContext()`)...yields the same error. So it doesn't appear to be unique to the custom index.

Comment: I've opened a ticket with Sitecore and will follow up.

Comment: @nsturdivant any follow up?

Comment: @MarkGibbons I do have some follow up; apologies for the delay and thank you for bumping. I eventually received a hotfix from Sitecore support to address the run-time exception noted in my question. Here's the link: https://sitecore.box.com/s/t6zu0s9uv2f8hioqpu0s5qgl8mvt0jol; reference number 341746. Note that this hotfix is specifically for Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1. I'm holding of on answering my own question until I have the patch in place and am able to use the SXA implementation of the WithinRadius() method to drive a geospatial Azure search query.

Comment: Looking at that hotfix it seems very specific to your solution unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and 'fixed' it by creating an extension method that creates a new `LinqToCloudIndex<TItem>`. I say 'fixed' because I was not able to identify the exact cause of the problem. But by recreating the `LinqToCloudIndex` I was able to overcome the error. The best solution would be a proper fix by Sitecore.

Here are the details of my solution. First let's take a look at the `LinqToCloudIndex` Class. The constructor takes the following 3 arguments:

```
LinqToCloudIndex(CloudSearchSearchContext context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts, ServiceCollectionClient serviceCollectionClient);
```

In my extension method I pass the latter 3 arguments.

- `CloudSearchSearchContext`: I cast my `IProviderSearchContext` to the `CloudSearchSearchContext`
- `IExecutionContext[]`: I don't use any ExecutionContext so I pass `null`
- `ServiceCollectionClient`: I recreate a new instance of `ServiceCollectionClient`

**The extension method**

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Query;
using System.Linq;

namespace Foundation.Search.Extensions
{
    public static class SearchExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TItem> GetMyQueryable<TItem>(this IProviderSearchContext context, bool isAzure)
        {
            if (isAzure)
            {
                // create new LinqToCloudIndex in order to overcome the error:
                // Constructor on type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.LinqToCloudIndex`1[[xxx]]' not found.
                var linqToCloudIndex = new LinqToCloudIndex<TItem>((CloudSearchSearchContext)context, null, new ServiceCollectionClient());
                return linqToCloudIndex.GetQueryable();
            }

            // just return the GetQueryable when using Solr or Lucene
            return context.GetQueryable<TItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Using the extension method**

As you can see i'm using `context.GetMyQueryable` instead of `context.GetQueryable`:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("yourindex").CreateSearchContext())
{
    string searchDefine = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetAppSetting("search:define");
    var results = context.GetMyQueryable<MySearchResultItem>(searchDefine.Equals("Azure", System.StringComparison.CurrentCulture)).Where(...)...
}
```

**Version notes**

- Sitecore XM 9.1.0 (rev. 001564)
- Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.8 rev. 181112 for 9.1

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it does seem to be a viable workaround for the original issue. However, per my comments on the question, Sitecore did issue a hotfix to address the run-time exception I was seeing.